# React Native: selectedDays.includes is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm new to react-native and I have an input where I can choose multiple days of a week, if I click on a day which is alreadyAdded the day is removed from selectedDays array, however when I click on a day I get the following error:

```
TypeError: selectedDays.includes is not a function. (In selectedDays.includes(index+1) selectedDays.includes is undefined
```

My code:

```
const [ dayOptions, setDayOptions ] = useState([ 'Lunes','Martes','Miercoles','Jueves','Viernes','Sabado','Domingo']);
    const [ selectedDays, setSelectedDays ] = useState([1]);


const clickedDay = (id)=>
    {
        const index = selectedDays.indexOf(id);
        if (index > -1)
        {
            setSelectedDays(selectedDays.splice(index, 1));
        }
        else
        {
            setSelectedDays(selectedDays.push(id));    
        }
    }


<View style={{ width:'100%',height:45,flexDirection:'row',alignItems:'center',flexWrap:'nowrap', justifyContent:'space-between' }}>
                        {dayOptions.map((option,index) => {return (
                        <TouchableOpacity  key={option.title} onPress = {() => {clickedDayOptions(index+1) }} style={{ width:'13.2%', height:'100%', flexDirection:'row', alignItems:'center',justifyContent:'center', borderRadius:5,borderWidth:1, borderColor:'rgba(0,0,0,0.2)', ...selectedDays.includes(index+1) ? { backgroundColor: 'rgb(255,52,89)' } : { backgroundColor:'white' }, }}>
                            <Text style={{ fontWeight:'bold',fontSize:14, ...selectedDays.includes(index+1) ? { color: 'white' } : { color:'rgb(68,68,68)' }, }}>{ option }</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>)
                    })}     
</View>
```

I tried changing includes for indexOf() > 1 and I get the same error, I usually get this when it's not an array but I defined selectedDays as an array in hooks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setSelectedDays(selectedDays.push(id));` Generally `Array.prototype.push` will return the length of the array after push operation is done, so here we are making `Array` to `number` so that you are getting indexOf, includes is not a function error because it's a number type

Try like below

```
const clickedDay = (id) => {
  const index = selectedDays.indexOf(id);
  if (index > -1) {
    selectedDays.splice(index, 1)
    setSelectedDays([...selectedDays]);
  } else {
    setSelectedDays([...selectedDays, id]);
  }
};
```

Comment: Hey this worked! However now when I click on an already added day, all days except for the day I just clicked are removed from the array, do you have any idea why?

Comment: yes updated the answer if answer is helpful please accept as an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
  const clickedDay = (id) => {
const index = selectedDays.indexOf(id);
if (index > -1) {
  const days = selectedDays.filter((idx) => idx !== id);
  setSelectedDays(days);
} else {
  setSelectedDays([...selectedDays, id]);
}
```

};

Comment: Please do not only post your code. Please add some description to the code.